# do we have privileges to process the model and update its values before saving in database or just add model directly received from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, model, upload

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

upload file and view model
when I trace the project it goes fine upto savechanges then rutrn the above error , id is hidden no problem with that, what i guess is the problem because of that I am taking file and process them to bytes variavles and assign them to the model , is that correct or is there any another way

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private col_details db = new col_details();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Index(col_details mod, HttpPostedFileBase[] files) 

    {
          if (Files.ElementAt(0) != null)
        {
            var file1 = Files.ElementAt(0);
            if (file1 != null && file1.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                using (BinaryReader br = new 
                  BinaryReader(file1.InputStream))
                {
                    bytes1 = br.ReadBytes(file1.ContentLength);
                    mod.degree_file= bytes1;
                }
        }
                 if (Files.ElementAt(1) != null)
        {
            var file2 = Files.ElementAt(1);
            if (file2 != null && file2.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                using (BinaryReader br = new 
                 BinaryReader(file1.InputStream))
                {
                    bytes2 = br.ReadBytes(file2.ContentLength);
                    mod.passport= bytes2;
                }
        }
       db.col_details.Add(new col_details
            {
                name = mod.name,
                Nid = mod.Nid,
                passport = mod.passport,
                degree = mod.degree,
                degree_file = mod.degree_file,
                aggregate = mod.aggregate,
                 });
           db.SaveChanges();
               return view();
            }
```

The view Model is here

from the view I receive the files and the model data , then I should add the HttpPostedfile to the model variables which is identified as bytes in model and in database , when I trace it, it reached to db.savechanges with the model including all the values and that error appears

Comment: That code wont compile, even with corrected formatting

Comment: ok , then what changes has to be made

Comment: How should I know?  The code wont compile, you are expected to include a [MCVE] with your question

Comment: I really have no clue about that error why it is showing , when all the data is passed and processed perfectly , i thought maybe because of web.config or something else , so whats wrong in that code and and what I am suppose to either to change the syntax or what exactly need to be done

Comment: Read the [MCVE] link.  Your code does not compile, how can we try to replicate the issue or figure out what the problem is when you haven't provided a sufficient example?

Answer (score 0):

Id was not set to identity and auto incremented in database table